# No hyphenation in table of contents (with titletoc)

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

I am trying to turn off hyphenation in the table of contents. Here is a minimal working example with my `titletoc` setup:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\contentsmargin{4em}
\titlecontents{section}
   [15mm] % ie, 1.5em (chapter) + 2.3em
   {}
   {\hspace*{-5mm}\parbox[t][]{5mm}{\textbf{\thecontentslabel.}}}
   {\hspace*{-5mm}\parbox[t][]{5mm}{\textcolor{gray}{$\blacksquare$}}}
   {\titlerule*[1pc]{ }{\sffamily\bfseries\contentspage}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Eterogeneità dei rischi, assicurazione e soluzioni di mercato}

\end{document}
```

The result I obtain is what I want, except for the hyphenation in the table of contents ("Indice").

[image]

I tried a number of solutions to get rid of hyphenation, such as adding `\hyphenpenalty 1000` or `\raggedright` to the `<above-code>` and at the end of the `<numbered-entry-format>` arguments of `\titlecontents`, but the only result was to mess up alignment.

Comment: As always here you are much more likely to get help if you provide a full but minimal example others can copy and test as is. That said add `\raggedright` to your parboxes and remember that `\sf` has been deprecated since 1993! use `\sffamily`

Comment: But  parboxes are for the label, aren't they? In fact, I added `\raggedright` inside parboxes and there was no effect on the text

Comment: I never use `titletoc` so unfamiliar with the syntax. Provide a full but minimal example, then we'll see if someone who knows `titletoc` can help. BTW: `titletoc` has a manual, search for `ragged`.

Comment: I know it has a manual ;-)

Comment: I can't reproduce the output: with `babel` there's no hyphenation; without it, I get hyphenation both in the TOC and in the section title.

Comment: I modified and turned back to Italian, I think now the minimal example should reproduce what you see in the picture. In any case, I don't want hyphenation

Comment: If you're` happy with the TOC entries being ragged right, you could try `\begingroup \raggedright \tableofcontents \endgroup`.  (Not tested.)

Comment: I would be happy with raggedright entries, but unfortunately the solution you suggest does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `\filright` in the appropriate argument. I also suggest to use a zero width box for the section number.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\contentsmargin{3em}
\titlecontents{section}
   [15mm] % ie, 1.5em (chapter) + 2.3em
   {\filright}
   {\makebox[0pt][r]{\bfseries\thecontentslabel.\@ }}
   {\makebox[0pt][r]{\textcolor{gray}{$\blacksquare$ }}}
   {\titlerule*[1pc]{ }{\sffamily\bfseries\contentspage}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Eterogeneità dei rischi, assicurazione e soluzioni di mercato}

\setcounter{section}{9}

\section{Eterogeneità dei rischi, assicurazione e soluzioni di mercato}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For avoiding hyphenation in the section titles, modify them with `\titleformat` from `titlesec`.